# Linux: grepping last characters from file

Tags: grep

I have to perform a `grep` through a log file. The `grep` needs to include two expressions:

1. In the log "bpm-activation-fibra-up-kjar:0.0.2"
2. And it needs to end with ";1"

Here's an example log:

```
47141;212a386d-00bd-4d73-8a81-ed98d2fd82a6@pam@fibra-up-bpm-manager-activation;NULL;NULL;bpm-activation-fibra-up-kjar:0.0.2;pamadmin;NULL;-1;it.activationUpProcess;47870;activationUpProcess;1;1.0;0;NULL;24/07/2021 10:51;1
```

While the first `grep` works well, the second one does not work:

```
grep "bpm-activation-fibra-up-kjar:0.0.2" data-1647411104037.csv | grep ".*;1$"
```

No data is returned.
Can you recommend how to perform the second `grep` on the last two characters?

Comment: I tested the code, and for me it returns the line. You could write this as a single grep as well `grep "bpm-activation-fibra-up-kjar:0\.0\.2.*;1$" data-1647411104037.csv`

Comment: There seems to be a space at the end of your input. `;1$` will match a line that ends with `;1`, but not a line that ends with a space.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this, but I see two possible issues in your expressions:

- The presence of colons and other possibly wildcard characters in the first expression. (Proposal: use `fgrep`, which doesn't care about wildcards)
- The characters, preceding the `;1` in the second expression. (Proposal: drop the `.*`)

So I would opt for:

```
fgrep "bpm-activation-fibra-up-kjar:0.0.2" data-1647411104037.csv | grep ";1$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting `awk` script:

```
  awk '/bpm-activation-fibra-up-kjar:0.0.2/ && /;1$/ 1' data-1647411104037.csv
```